# Can we do conditional formatting in excel based on values in separate Sheet?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do conditional formatting based on the values in the separate sheet. For eg: I have Sheet1 where the table is like this

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1                                   
2                                   
3                                   
4                                   
5                                   
6                                   
7                                   
8                                   
9                                   
10
```

And Sheet2 has the same table with values like these,

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
5   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
6   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
7   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
8   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
9   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Now i want to highlight the cells in Sheet1 for the respective column in Sheet2 where the value is 1.

Comment: so you want the sheet 1 to blank always and just reflect the color

Comment: @PraveenDA Its not necessary that the cells are blank, they contain some other data, this is like a template

Comment: if that is case the below given answer should work for you..

Answer (score 1):

You can but I don't understand why you would want to do it that way though. You can follow the steps below:
 1. Select the cell (i.e. B1)
 2. Click `More Rules` from `Conditional Formatting` menu option
 3. In **`New Formatting Rule`** window, select **`Use a formula to determine which cells to format`**
 4. In formula bar have the following formula: `=Sheet2!$B$1=1`
 5. Chose a colour to highlight the cell

Repeat the process for each cell

Comment: i can use similar step using Vlookup in conditional formatting for the whole column. Carrying out this for each cell is more tedious.
My question is to solve this for the whole table in one formula